# What is used for Core Data Ordering?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, sql-order-by

Going off this question on SO [Ordered CoreData records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767542/ordered-coredata-records)

I understand that ordering data in a Core Data, by orderID is not possible.
When you use:

```
sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES
```

It sorts in alphabetical order, when you select `NO` then the order appears to be random, but not every time on a new launch.

Does anyone know what order is being chosen? If it was random, then would it not have to change every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's supposed to be descending.